# reference on limsup and liminf for functions

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, limsup-and-liminf

I need a reference well-explaining (definitions and useful properties) the notions of upper limit and lower limit for **functions** defined on a topological space

Thank you.

Comment: This should be in almost any real analysis book. See for example Bruckner, Bruckner, and Thomson, [Elementary Real Analysis](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf), (free legal PDF), section 5.3.

Comment: Thank you Bungo.
Maybe I had to precise that it is in a topological space setting and generally (as in Elementary Rean Analysis) the notions are treated as exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Any standard analysis book should include a section on them, or at least some exercises. Personally, when I was learning about these not so long ago, I found the following wikipedia page more helpful than usual.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior

Comment: Thank you for your interest. When the departure space is a topological space, most of the books I looked on were considering these limit notions as elementary !